# mod-wsgi & apache & pyramid (pylonsproject)

Tags: python, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, pyramid

i have a problem with running pyramid site under apache+mod-wsgi. the problem is that i can't tell apache which python interpretor is the right one for the site it serve. i have several virtual environments and i would like to take those python interpretors.

i added this code to my apache config:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=karantan group=karantan processes=1 threads=4 python-    path=/home/karantan/pyramid1.0/bin/python
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/karantan/myproject/pyramid.wsgi

<Directory /home/karantan/myproject>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

there is also a parameter called WSGIPythonHome that tells apache which interpretor is the right one but i can't put it in this config because it is global variable (or something like that...)

so how do i run pyramid site with virtual environment under apache?

as stated above my main problem (i think) is that apache always runs pyramid with default system python interpretor (/usr/bin/python). how do i tell apache that it must take the one from the virtualenv.???

Comment: Seriously 2 you back!?!?! no i was just bored and want to ask a question so you guys can get reputation up... :o
i am still trying to get it work btw (no success)

Comment: ok it works now. in ALLDIRS i had to put the dir of my project, in pruduction.ini i had to write the path to mako dirs and in apache conf i had to write another dit for the virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Documentation explaining how to use virtual environments with mod_wsgi can be found at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Comment: and because it is not working i asked here! also i didn't ask where the documentation can be found!

Comment: Where in the documentation does it tell you to set python-path to be the path to the Python executable? As shown in example in the documentation it is meant to be the site-packages directory of the Python virtual environment. Don't follow the documentation and your chances of it working are reduced.

Comment: yes i fixed that soon after i posted this... anyway it works now (i wrote what was the problem on my last comment on main post)